# Multiple FileUpload with Ajax (different sizes to the server)

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, upload, resize

I have been making a project and I need to upload an image. When the user selects images, 300x300 size images will be uploaded. When finished, 700x700 size of same images will be uploaded. Finally the original version of the images will be uploaded to the server.

In short user will select images one time and I want to upload images that selected by user as the different sizes to the server.

How can I make this project using .NET and AJAX?

Comment: You do not want to upload the image multiple times. Just upload once and resize in the server code (.NET)

Comment: thanks your response, but firstly I want to upload 300x300 size images. when finished, 700x700 size images finally the original images upload to server.